# Add Windows 7 to local domain

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, windows-domain

I just setup a domain called foo.local. It is running on an internal network that is being NATed out. The domain controller is running with a static IP address.

How do I get a windows 7 computer to join the domain?

Normally to join a domain you click Computer->Properties-> Change... -> Member of -> Domain

Then I input foo.local.

The problem is that the computer is trying to connect to the domain controller by a DNS name, and I don't have a DNS server running on the local network.

Is there a way I can tell Windows 7 to look at a static IP address to join the domain?

Comment: how did you setup the domain? Do you have a Windows Server in place configured as "Domain Controller"?

Comment: See: [Is it possible to link a domain to my server without a DNS?](http://superuser.com/q/481301/82421)

Comment: It is setup as a domain controller, and I've added several users.

Comment: If you edit your PC's ETC/HOSTS file to resolve the DC's IP, your PC will then find your DC on your internal network. The only other solution is to add a DNS server to a computer on your network, like on your Domain Controller, which can resolve all network addresses.

Comment: I didn't realize that having a DNS service record was required for Active Directory. I setup my DNS server.

Comment: What version of Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Update the file "`hosts`" in the folder:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\
```

to include the IP address and hostname of your Domain Controller, per:
[How to edit the hosts in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/145429/how-to-edit-the-hosts-in-windows-7)